# understand proof Cauchy Pompeiuu formula

Tags: complex-analysis

The statement of Cauchy Pompeiuu formula is as followed:

Let $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ compact with piecewise $C^1$ boundary $\partial K$. Then for every $f \in C^1(K,\mathbb{C})$,

$f(w)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial K} \frac{f(z)}{z-w} dz - \int_{K} \frac{1}{\pi (z-w)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} \frac{i}{2}dz \wedge d\bar{z}$.

The first step of the proof is as followed:

$\int_{K} \frac{1}{\pi (z-w)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} \frac{i}{2}dz \wedge d\bar{z} = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{K-B(w,\epsilon)} \frac{1}{\pi (z-w)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} \frac{i}{2}dz \wedge d\bar{z}$

So basically, we remove a ball around $w$ with radius $\epsilon$ to integrate a function with singularity, and let $\epsilon$ goes to 0. My question is why are we allowed do this? Is this a case of Cauchy Principal Value of an integral, or are we using Lebesgue dominated/monotone convergence theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's due to dominated convergence. For simplicity in notation, suppose $w=0$. The function $f$ is assumed $C^1$ on $K$, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}$ is bounded on $K$, so doesn't affect convergence. You are right to be worried because $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is not integrable near the origin in 1-dimension. The nice thing is that you're now in 2-dimensions, so although you still have the reciprocal denominator $\frac{1}{z}$, the difference is that you're integrating the form $\frac{1}{z}\,dz\wedge d\overline{z}$. In other words ignoring constant factors, the question is whether or not the integral
\begin{align}
\int_D\frac{1}{|(x,y)|}dx\,dy
\end{align}
is finite (here $D$ is the unit disc centered at the origin). By changing variables to polar coordinates, we see that
\begin{align}
\int_D\frac{1}{|(x,y)|}dx\,dy&=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{r}r\,d\theta\,dr=2\pi<\infty.
\end{align}
So, although $\frac{1}{z}$ has a singularity at the origin in $\Bbb{C}$, it is an integrable singularity with respect to the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure (because $dz\wedge d\overline{z}\sim dx\wedge dy=r\,dr\wedge d\theta$). Just FYI: in $n$-dimensions, $\int_{B_{1}(0)}\frac{1}{\|x\|^s}\,d^nx$ is finite if and only if $(n-1)-s>-1$, i.e if and only if $s<n$ (in the case above, $s=1$ and $n=2$).

Putting this all together, $\frac{1}{(z-w)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{i}{2}\,dz\wedge d\overline{z}$ is a $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{C})=L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^2)$ (locally integrable) differential form in the sense that we can write it as $\phi(x,y)\,dx\wedge dy$ for some $\phi$ whose integral over compact sets is finite. So, it is valid by Dominated convergence ($|\phi|$ serves as the dominating function) to first remove an $\epsilon$ ball around the point $w$, calculate integrals, and finally take limits.